# Error when Compiling PDCurses36 with TDM GCC 5.1.0

Tags: c++, mingw, pdcurses

I have recently been struggling to build the source code for pdcurses36 despite following the instructions provided in the README.md.  For whatever reason, I'm always left with the same error, as the "recipe for target 'pdcdisp.o' failed".  This is the error prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\pdcurs36\wincon>mingw32-make -f makefile
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -I.. ../wincon/pdcdisp.c
../wincon/pdcdisp.c: In function '_new_packet':
../wincon/pdcdisp.c:211:28: error: 'COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE' undeclared (first use in this function)
             mapped_attr |= COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE;
                            ^
../wincon/pdcdisp.c:211:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../wincon/pdcdisp.c:213:28: error: 'COMMON_LVB_GRID_LVERTICAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
             mapped_attr |= COMMON_LVB_GRID_LVERTICAL;
                            ^
../wincon/pdcdisp.c:215:28: error: 'COMMON_LVB_GRID_RVERTICAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
             mapped_attr |= COMMON_LVB_GRID_RVERTICAL;
                            ^
makefile:94: recipe for target 'pdcdisp.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [pdcdisp.o] Error 1
```

These are the commands I've issued to the command prompt:

```
set PDCURSES_SRCDIR = C:\...\pdcurs36

path = C:\...\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin

cd C:\...\pdcurs36\wincon

mingw32-make -f Makefile
```

I am currently using TDM GCC 5.1.0 (what was provided with the binary build of codeblocks 17.12) and [pdcurs36.zip from the repository provided from the official site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/3.6/).  My OS is Windows 10.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I meant version 17.12 of codeblocks

Comment: I assume you meant Codeblocks 17.12?

Comment: Yep.  It's been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to **comment**, but you might be interested in [this PDCurses commit](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/commit/242b47d90df2ace5a20218d60e75283ec18a613c) to pdcdisp.c.

> warning on an old compiler; replaced COMMON_LVB_* with numbers to
>   appease some old compilers. After Simon Sobisch.

Looks like GCC 5.1.0 just doesn't define those macros, so they hardcoded the values:

```
0x8000; /* COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE */
0x0800; /* COMMON_LVB_GRID_LVERTICAL */
0x1000; /* COMMON_LVB_GRID_RVERTICAL */
```

Comment: While the commit fixed pdcdisp.c, I wasn't able to get pdcscrn to work.
https://pastebin.com/axMv3D8V
Think I should switch to an older version of pdcurses?

Comment: I'd suggest a newer version of MinGW, personally.

Comment: I'll comment further, but not here, to adhere to Stackoverflow guidelines. Watch the PDCurses GitHub in the next few days.

Comment: It looks like TDM hasn't released a build of GCC since 2015. I would also install MinGW. They have a good setup GUI (almost a package manager) and a helpful Getting Started. You can also direct CodeBlocks to use that toolchain pretty easily.

Comment: Did anyone get this working, as I am really stuck on this